# wcf service are not working in self network

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am new to WCF. I have a WCF Service application created in VS 2012.

When I execute it from VS, it runs and shows the service running in the browser.

I now want to create a client to test the service. How can I do this?

Service code as follows:

```
public class CallList : ICallList
{
    public String List(String id,String name)
    {            
        String Message;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CallList;Integrated Security=True");//Data Source=ANDROID-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CallList;Integrated Security=True
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallLog(id,name) values(@id,@name)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            Message =  " Details inserted successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = " Details not inserted successfully";
        }

        con.Close();

        return Message;           
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me with how to test this service.

Comment: Are you sure the actual communication workds as desired? If not, I suggest the tool SoapUI to test the communication; it can be foundt at http://www.soapui.org/ - furthermore it is unclear how the code in the question relates to the WCF service. Is ist possible that the problem is related to the database alone?

Comment: I suggest debugging both server and client side to see if the actual communication works.

Comment: client(is a mobile) i dont have chance to debug..can you explain how to debug server....Thanks @codor

Comment: Basically I meant setting a breakpoint within some service implementation and testing whether it is reached.

Comment: @codor, Placed breakpoint in code and click view in browser and it is not reach to breakpoint atleast first line of code

Comment: @codor this webservice syntax(if client send values server want to store in database) is correct

Comment: You need to show us more code. For example the ICallList definition and also your service configuration file.

Comment: If you say it is working with browser means `.svc` is browsable, to test this, you need to create a console project and add service reference ( use .svc url), or use Fiddler, postman rest client in chrome to test, then if that is not working, post error message here!

Comment: @Tom Redfern   only this code in ICallList [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://localhost/Service")]
    public interface ICallList
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String List(String id, String name);
    }

Comment: @ArindamNayak how to upload and where to upload this code in domain..i register one domain. can someone explain this

Comment: Why you need to upload ? You were asking for testing WCF, right?

Comment: yes,its working fine after console application.now i need to upload to server and post URL,NAMESPACE and METHODNAME to client(mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't see any service Implementation in your code.but Here is a simple [article](http://akothalawala.blogspot.com/2013/08/wcf-windows-communication-foundation.html) I wrote while ago. it contain how to create WCF service and test it using WCF Test client. another way to test your application is

1. Create a Console Application Project.
2. Copy service URL from the browser and then right click on project and select add service reference and then paste the URL you copied.
3. Then add your code as below. in your program.cs class

   ```
   ICalculatorClient calcClient = new CalculatorClient());
   int value1 = 100;
   int value2 = 15;
   double result = calcClient.Addition(value1, value2);
   Console.WriteLine("Addition({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);
   ```

Note : you can find more information regarding this topic in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how to upload and where to upload this code in domain..i register one domain. can someone explain this